# Get Windows Phone app store ProductID prior to submission

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-store

Is there any way of finding out the store generated ProductID prior to submission of a new app? It used to be that we could create a store app and (without submitting) get its allocated ProductID and then paste this into our WMAppManifest.xml in order to be able to set up Facebook social login that requires the app ProductID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as far as I know. You can submit the app as hidden so no one downloads it, get the id, then add the Facebook integration and then submit it again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using \

```
 var appId = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId;
```

See MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.appid?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: The question was "prior" to public submission to the store windows phone store. The store will generate a new ProductId when the app is first submitted, and that ProductId will be associated for the lifetime of the app in the store :-)